# What mysql INT for 0,1,2 or 3?

Tags: mysql, int

What should I use as mysql column type for a value that can either be 0, 1, 2 or , 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If space isn't tight (and it rarely is these days), I'd just use `int` and move on to more interesting things. If space is tight, then a `tinyint` (one byte) would make sense. The numeric types with their ranges and storage requirements is here:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html

An `enum` might be an option:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html

Comment: I never like posing this argument but enum is one of those things I get yelled at for favoring since it is incompatible should one choose to migrate to some DB like oracle or something. I argue that I'm never going to change, but hey - I still get yelled at. Sometimes it's good to know how less common datatypes are perceived though.

Comment: @Kai: `tinyint` is also MySQL-specific and other databases have their own way of doing things like `enum`. The portability argument doesn't hold much water, MySQL is sloppy enough (silent truncation, no CHECK constraints, automatic casting, ...) that a minor data type issue will be the least of your worries if you're moving to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would use tinyint(1)... and I have to type more cause SO requires at least 30 characters